# React onClick method works with 1 click behind for excuting an if statment and setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, onclick

I've encountered a problem that  I cant find a solution  too:
The scenario is this

On each reload the `this.state.wanted_input` will generate a random 3 digits number that will be inserted in the first paragraph ( for instance lets say 573 ), also the second paragraph's content is `this.state.stage_input` which will be aways ("") on reload.

Down below I have 10 buttons (from 0 to 9), with a value of `this.state.buttonsS[index]` ... this purpose of that is that i have a `shuffleArray()` method that changes the buttons values every time a button is clicked.

The constructor is that :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.incertInStageInput = this.incertInStageInput.bind(this);
  this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  this.state={
    stage_input:'',
    wanted_input: Math.floor( Math.random()*799 ) + 100,
    buttonsS:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }

 }
```

In the `render()` function I have 2 paragraphs:

the content of the one is:

```
{this.state.wanted_input}
```

the content of the second is:

```
{this.state.stage_input}
```

Here is the buttons `onClick` function :

```
  onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonClick( this.state.buttonsS[0] )}}
  onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonClick( this.state.buttonsS[1] )}}
  onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonClick( this.state.buttonsS[2] )}}
  ...(e.t.)
```

The method that the buttons execud is this:

```
  handleButtonClick(x){
    this.incertInStageInput(x);
    this.shuffleArray();
  }
```

The main method this:

```
  incertInStageInput(value){

    this.setState({stage_input: this.state.stage_input + value});

    console.log(this.state.stage_input);
    if (this.state.stage_input == this.state.wanted_input) {
      //stuff to do if true...
    }
  }
```

The main  idea is  that : 
  First i get the number 573 ... i have the buttons ready to be clicked ... i click the button 5 the state changes to `this.state.stage_input` + `value` .. value is 5 
  so it changes to "" + 5 which resolves to "5", but the `console.log(this.state.stage_input);` outputs and "" .. next I click 7 ..the state changes to "5" + "7" which is "57" but the `console.log(this.state.stage_input);` outputs "5"...??? Finally I click button 3 .. the state is "573" and the `console.log(this.state.stage_input);` returns "57" ... and now when I click  no matter which button the `incertInStageInput(value)` metod is executed for fourth time and that the `IF` statment is working .....

I wonder why when clicking the buttons and executing the function , the `(this.state.stage_input == this.state.wanted_input)` works after the fourth click ... HOW CAN I MAKE THE METHOD COMPARE THE NEW `stage_input` STATE AND THE  `wanted_input` DYNAMICALLY ?

Answer (score 3):

You will not get value here `console.log(this.state.stage_input);` , if you want to get updated value just after it is set

Here you go, You need to do it like this :

```
incertInStageInput(value){
    this.setState({stage_input: this.state.stage_input + value} , () => {
        console.log(this.state.stage_input);
        if (this.state.stage_input == this.state.wanted_input) {
        //stuff to do if true...
        }
    });
}
```

Reason :

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

For more details , please read [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

That is be because [this.setState is async](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3). You should use a `callback` or `componentDidUpdate` (which is what the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) recommend) to read state right after `this.setState`.